# read stream from s3 with Clojure/Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, clojure

I have a large file on s3 which I wish to decode and parse as it downloads. I happen to be using the clojure [Amazonica library](https://github.com/mcohen01/amazonica), but any library will do.

I can easily get a stream:

```
(def stream (-> (get-object "some-s3-bucket" "some-object-key") :input-stream))

; returns: #<S3ObjectInputStream com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectInputStream
```

but how do I read the stream? 
Can I read it a line at a time (the decompressed contents are JSON lines)?

(If there's any ambiguity in my question, I am only concerned with the reading of the stream, not any part of the gzip decoding)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since [`S3ObjectInputStream`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3ObjectInputStream.html) happens to extend `java.io.InputStream`, you can:

1. Use [Clojure's `reader`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.java.io/reader) function to get a `BufferedReader` on it.
2. Read data from the reader in any way Clojure allows to.

   - Use [`line-seq`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/line-seq) to get a lazy sequence of lines from the `BufferedReader`. If that makes sense for your JSON. It may not.
   - Use a lazy JSON parser, such as [`clj-lazy-json`](https://github.com/michalmarczyk/clj-lazy-json). This particular one can even handle a bare stream, so step (1) can be safely skipped with it.

Answer (score 8):

If it's helpful to anyone, this is what I came up with following D-Side's helpful response.

```
(ns some-project.get-s3-stream
    (:require [aws.sdk.s3 :as s3])
    (:require [clojure.java.io :as io])
    (:use [amazonica.aws.s3])
    (:import [java.util.zip GZIPInputStream]))

(def bucket "some-s3-bucket")
(def object-key "some-object-key")

(def seq-of-json-lines
  (->
   (get-object bucket object-key)
   :object-content
   (java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.)
   io/reader
   line-seq))
```